# UseState or UseReducer to manage FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-reducer

UseState or UseReducer to manage FormData

I have a question, for render formdata in react (for example login, register, contact form data) it's better usereducer or usestate?

Comment: `useState` is a wrapper around `useReducer` I believe. Also, what do you mean by better? `useState` is probably better from a code organization/readability standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both have pros and cons here is some info from the [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/extracting-state-logic-into-a-reducer#comparing-usestate-and-usereducer):

> - Code size: Generally, with useState you have to write less code upfront. With useReducer, you have to write both a reducer function
>   and dispatch actions. However, useReducer can help cut down on the
>   code if many event handlers modify state in a similar way.
> - Readability: useState is very easy to read when the state updates are simple. When they get more complex, they can bloat your
>   component’s code and make it difficult to scan. In this case,
>   useReducer lets you cleanly separate the how of update logic from the
>   what happened of event handlers.
> - Debugging: When you have a bug with useState, it can be difficult to tell where the state was set incorrectly, and why. With useReducer,
>   you can add a console log into your reducer to see every state update,
>   and why it happened (due to which action). If each action is correct,
>   you’ll know that the mistake is in the reducer logic itself. However,
>   you have to step through more code than with useState.
> - Testing: A reducer is a pure function that doesn’t depend on your component. This means that you can export and test it separately in
>   isolation. While generally it’s best to test components in a more
>   realistic environment, for complex state update logic it can be useful
>   to assert that your reducer returns a particular state for a
>   particular initial state and action.
> - Personal preference: Some people like reducers, others don’t. That’s okay. It’s a matter of preference. You can always convert between
>   useState and useReducer back and forth: they are equivalent!
>
> We recommend using a reducer if you often encounter bugs due to
> incorrect state updates in some component, and want to introduce more
> structure to its code. You don’t have to use reducers for everything:
> feel free to mix and match! You can even useState and useReducer in
> the same component.

Comment: very complete answer, thanks